# Making Columns with Arrays, wrong output

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So I was trying to make some simple columns in Java (Yes, I am very new to this), and I just can't get it to 'stand' properly...

My code is the following:

```
int[][] grid = {
            {3, 5, 2434},
            {2, 4},
            {1, 2, 3, 4}
        };
```

combined with:

```
    for(int row=0; row<grid.length; row++){
        for (int col=0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.println(grid[row][col] + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Which gives me this result:

3
5
2434

2
4

1
2
3
4

Which leads me to my confusion.. Shoudn't "\t" just move them like "tab", instead of giving them a new line?

I appreciate the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`. `println` automatically adds a linebreak and renders your tab useless.

```
for(int row=0; row<grid.length; row++){
    for (int col=0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.print(grid[row][col] + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(grid[row][col] + "\t");
```

You are using `println` which automatically adds a linefeed at the end of the `String` you pass it.

Try using `System.out.print()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you are using

```
System.out.println() ;
```

this method by default adds a new line at the end of the output.

if you don't want this behaviour use

`System.out.print();`

Answer (score 1):

The next line is because of the method `println()` and not because of `\t`
use `print()` instead

Your method behaves as though it invokes `print(yourParameters)` and then println() which says

> **Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string**. The
>   line separator string is defined by the system property
>   line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character
>   ('\n').

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use System.out.print() instead of System.out.prinln() in order to avoid line feed

Answer (score 0):

Use System.out.print(). the println command creates a new line at the end of every command , as if you wrote System.out.print(text+"\n").